# I call 'em witches

Tags: curves

I'm experimenting with a (new?) way of drawing curves - see [**Desmos**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rz505mvio5) and [**whisk**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfQI5.png) - that I have not encountered anywhere else, and I was wondering if these have a name. The closest things I found were the [witch of Agnesi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_of_Agnesi), [ogives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogive) and the [line of beauty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_beauty).

The curves are defined by the vector space of $\vec b$ between $t = 0$ and $t= 1$ for predetermined values of $R_1$ and $R_2$:

$0≤t≤1$

$R = [-1:1, -1:1]$

$r = R_1 + t(R_2 - R_1)$

$\vec a = [t, 0]$

$\vec c = [\frac{1-\cos(\pi t)}{2}, \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{2}]$

$\vec b = \vec a + r(\vec c - \vec a)$

**EDIT:** I recombined two positive curves to achieve more usable results for negative values, and reintroduced the negative curve as a pinch factor:

[**[Desmos]**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8qw5pkgand)

Comment: Could you describe what characteristics these curves have?  (Otherwise I'm inclined to call them "curves")

Comment: Does this meet the qualifications?

Comment: Look at 'em [dance](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1dxofensru)! :)

Comment: I think I might be aiming for [this](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Two-arcs-blended-together-to-obtain-a-circle-spline-shown-as-a-red-curve_fig4_341476435) state-of-the-art approach.